# how to start a new activity from anther activity ... in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to start a new activity from ab activity that (extends from Linearlayout) .. but this code is not right

```
Intent i = new Intent(SearchResultForm.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

...
...

```
public class SearchResultForm extends LinearLayout{ ...
```

and i get this error ..

> > No enclosing instance of the type SearchResultForm is accessible in scope

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing since I can't see the rest of your code, but try:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.getPackageName());
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside an activity's method, just pass `this` as the first parameter.