# How do I call a class in the print function?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in developing and I know the question may sounds very basic but, let me cut to the chase: here is my class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lvPhone;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvPhone = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPhone);

        List<PhoneBook> listPhoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBook>();
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 
                "blah_blah", "384765345667", "something@someprovider.com"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher),
                "blah_blah", "34856834796", "something@someprovider.com"));
        listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook( 
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher),
                "blah_name", "868734633", "something@someprovider.com"));
        PhoneBookAdapter adapter = new PhoneBookAdapter(this, listPhoneBook);
        lvPhone.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and here I'd like it to be "attached" so then when the button is clicked the phone book comes up.

```
public void addListenerOnButton(){

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pb_button);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,//phone_book goes here
            "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//no toaster instead

        }

    });
}
```

Would any of you please help? This is going to be really helpful for me. And please if you do answer, try to explain as you're explaining to a "Java_moron" :) (as through as possible please)

[Now I did try the chat room, no reputation point so that didn't happen and I tried to google as much as possible couldn't find anything helpful; maybe there was answer but my lack of knowledge failed me.]
Thank you,

[EDIT: Or instead of using the phone book class, how can I call contacts from phone's native contact list? Anything would be helpful really.]

Comment: [Start a new Activity?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227919/how-to-start-a-new-activity-from-anther-activity-in-android

That's probably what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option to start would be to activate a native activity that will bring up phone book contacts and show them to the user as a list. Selected contacts is then passed to starting activity.

Explanation:

You can learn how to start an activity and receive result from the following link:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Basically the main code do that is as follows:

```
   static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
   ...
   private void pickContact() {
       Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, new Uri("content://contacts"));
       pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
       startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
    }
```

Note that the user will be calling the startActivityForResult method this will start a new activity and once that activity is finished the System will call onActivityResult() method of the original Activity and here you will receive results to which contacts has been selected.

Comment: you welcome please can you accept/voteup the answer...many thanks

Comment: Apologies, I did not realise there's an accept button and regarding my voting status (:p), I am not yet able to vote-up due to low reputation point!

Comment: Thank you! that is fine. If you find something useful voteup and if you have found an answer to the question you have asked then accept the answer. Don't worry soon you will get enough reputations and you will unlock many of the features.